# How to order a query on multiple fields in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to order a query on multiple fields in `Firestore` using `Flutter`. I use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sgees').orderBy('uid').orderBy('timestamp').get()`. But I get the following error:

```
Listen for Query(target=Query(sgees order by uid, timestamp, __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/myfirebaseprojectname/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck9wcm9qZWN0cy9mbHV0dGVyLXNhbGFtLWFwcC9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvc2dlZXMvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaBwoDdWlkEAEaDQoJdGltZXN0YW1wEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ
Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/myfirebaseprojectname/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck9wcm9qZWN0cy9mbHV0dGVyLXNhbGFtLWFwcC9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvc2dlZXMvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaBwoDdWlkEAEaDQoJdGltZXN0YW1wEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ
```

What is the solution? Thanks in advance.